# Monitor and Alert helm deployed environments in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, slack, mattermost

Is there any way to monitor the helm deployed applications in Kubernetes. I just want to get alert/notification when a helm app version is upgraded or changed.

Comment: We have this functionality natively via Reliza - if you connect it to slack - see here for a tutorial - https://worklifenotes.com/2023/05/02/reliza-cd-tutorial-deploying-on-kubernetes/